# can you play minecraft with your freinds on Xbox one slim when I'm on Xbox one?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My friends on xbox one s and I'm on Xbox one and we don't know if we can play together, we have always wanted to play together, but he needed a Xbox, but he got a Xbox one s, so pls message if you can help.

Comment: They are the same consoles.  The Xbox One Slim is just a "face lifted" Xbox One.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As far as gaming is concerned an Xbox One and an Xbox One Slim are the same thing, just different releases of the same system. You will both need an internet connection, an Xbox Live account, and a copy of the game, but the fact that one is an original and the other is a slim will not stop you from playing together.